# Ruby on Rails in production error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just put my Rails app online in production. And I kind of have two problems:

1. I get a 500 on my website for which the production.log says:

   `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10.0ms
   ActionView::Template::Error (./icons/icon_nameplate.png isn't precompiled):`

   For this what I tried is running the following command:

   `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

   This didn't work. I want to say that when I run the server locally on my computer with rails server everything works just fine.

   Output of `bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile --trace`:

   `** Invoke assets:clean (first_time)
   ** Execute assets:clean
   /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /usr/local/bin/rake assets:clean:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
   ** Invoke assets:clean:all (first_time)
   ** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
   ** Execute assets:environment
   ** Invoke environment (first_time)
   ** Execute environment
   ** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
   ** Execute tmp:cache:clear
   ** Execute assets:clean:all
   rm -rf /home/celliptic/public/assets
   ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
   ** Execute assets:precompile
   /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /usr/local/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
   ** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
   ** Execute assets:precompile:all
   ** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
   ** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
   ** Execute assets:environment
   ** Invoke environment (first_time)
   ** Execute environment
   ** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
   ** Execute tmp:cache:clear
   ** Execute assets:precompile:primary
   ** Invoke assets:precompile:nondigest (first_time)
   ** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
   ** Execute assets:environment
   ** Invoke environment (first_time)
   ** Execute environment
   ** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
   ** Execute tmp:cache:clear
   ** Execute assets:precompile:nondigest`
2. The second problem may be why the first one didn't get corrected after precompilation. It's just that any modification on the server isn't directly reflected on the website. Is it normal? Is it because of some kind of proxy caching my website?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: try this: bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile --trace

Comment: just added output to the question

Comment: I think you should check your settings in your environments/production.rb. Please refer to the Rails guides. You can simulate production mode in your local like this "rails s -e production"

Comment: ah.. run "touch tmp/restart.txt" in you server if you are using passenger

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile --trace
```

then spawn it if you are using passenger:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

then check again.

Comment: I ran both commands it didn't change anything. Still says that it's not precompiled

Comment: How do you call your image? Try to use image_path('myPic.png') when you are inside css or image_tag('myPic.png') in your view. There is also a helper called asset_path, you can use it. I think Rick Peck is correct, you might be calling it directly since we don't see the MD5 hash. If still no luck, really try to make sure that your settings are correct in your environments.

Answer (score 1):

The error you have: `ActionView::Template::Error (./icons/icon_nameplate.png isn't precompiled)`, to me, seems like you're trying to load a static asset when it's not there.

I would look at your views or CSS to where you referenced `icon_nameplate.png` - I believe the problem will likely be that you're trying to reference the file directly, and as it has not been compiled, it's unavailable. The proof of this would be that it's referencing a static (non fingerprinted) link

After you've followed `tungsten_carbide`'s directions, please let us know what happens

Answer (score 0):

Hi what webserver you are using? and under which Linux?

try those steps:

1. see if you got the permissions to write the compiled assets.
2. you sure you include it under application.css?
3. paste your complete css file maybe you use methods like asset-url which can cause the error you talk about.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. It works well now, but I don't really know which command made the deal. I've made:

1. `bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile --trace`
2. `touch tmp/restart.txt`
3. Changed `config.assets.compile = true` in production.rb
4. At this moment it didn't work, so I went to sleep. Woke up, load my website and it worked

So maybe it needed time to activate the changes or I don't know.

Still thank you for your help.